# Analog for bash `$0` in Nashorn

Tags: java-8, nashorn

I'd like to use Nashorn for shell scripting, however I can't find the analog of the Bash variable `$0` which tells me the path of the running script so that I could launch other scripts that are in the same folder (this is different from the *working directory*).

Comment: I've done something similar in one of my projects, it generally worked pretty well.  Either as a thin wrapper on jjs with my library in the classpath

https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/master/src/main/scripts/okshell

or launching an interpreter to run a script with some additional context

https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/jjs/JavascriptApiCommand.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__DIR__` and `__FILE__` values available in Nashorn JavaScript will help you implementing a substitute for `$0`. The former gives you the current file's directory; the latter, the file name.